# World Of Warcraft LUA API UnitClass() returns nil value

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

**Problem**

Weird situation when consuming the UnitClass() function from World Of Warcrafts lua API. It is returning nil. The parameter for it is a "target name", see the reference [here](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/UnitClass)

If I reload though, I do get a value back as I would expect. So the following is happening:

1. Log in with any character
2. print() the return values from the UnitClass() function call
3. it prints out nill for class and className
4. /reload the game
5. print() the return values from the UnitClass() function call
6. it prints out actual data this time, as one would expect

**What I Think Is Happening**

I think I need to wait for a specific event, not sure what event though. If I invoke the same script from the chat window I get values back after I log in or reload, which is how I thought it should work from my lua script

**Code**

ClassColors.lua

```
function GetUnitClassColor(UnitName)
    local class, classFileName = UnitClass(UnitName)
    local color = RAID_CLASS_COLORS[classFileName]

    print(class)
    print(classFileName)

    return color
end
```

core.lua (which has my initialisation code)

```
function GetCharacterData()
    local playerName = UnitName("Player")
    local playerRealm = GetRealmName()

    local playerNameRealm = playerName .. '-' .. playerRealm

    return playerNameRealm
end

----------------------Initialize----------------------------------

    local mainFrame = CreateFrame("Frame")
    mainFrame:RegisterEvent("ADDON_LOADED")
    mainFrame:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_LOGOUT")

    mainFrame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, arg1)

        local currentCharacter = GetCharacterData()
        local newCharacter = true

        if event == "ADDON_LOADED" and arg1 == "MyAddOn" then   

            local characterClassColor        = GetUnitClassColor(UnitName("Player"))
```

So you can see my intention was to get the color table returned and assigned to characterClassColor, but I get nothing at all just nill from class and classFileName variables in the GetUnitClassColor.

Thoughts on this? I've been looking at the events in the API docs to see if I'm missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by removing the `GetUnitClassColor(UnitName)` function and simply invoking `print(UnitClass("player"))`. Guess there is some internal logic I am not seeing where UnitClass can't handle the actual player's name at load time, but does recognise "player"

Comment: I believe you are right, GetUnitClassColor(UnitName) has too query the server while the player data is already available via the character details in your World of Warcraft files on your own pc.